# Covert string to a date bash

Tags: bash, unix

I am trying to convert ProcessedTime": 1545166011.794351 to a date using date function in bash script, what is the best way to convert it ?

Answer (score 3):

```
date -d @154166011.794351
```

Date command should work fine.

Comment: ...if GNU `date` is available.

Answer (score 1):

With GNU awk:

```
echo 154166011.794351 | awk '{print strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M:%S",$0)}'
```

Output:

```
1974-11-20 08:53:31
```

---

Source: https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/168317/74329